# angular - google recaptcha shows up only after reloading page?

Tags: javascript, angular, recaptcha

So i have problem with google recaptcha. It shows up only after refreshing page.

My code that is in `<body>` :

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SITE KEY"></div>
```

Captcha only shows up after i refresh page. Even when i click on some page and when i go back on same page captcha disappears and i must refresh page again. Any ideas ?

I tried with `grecaptcha.reset()` but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using grecaptcha.reset() in jquery document ready event.